# How many contexts for last_sig_coeff_x,y_prefix flag in HEVC?

Tags: encoding, entropy, hevc, h.265

I have been reading the standard **High Efficiency Video Coding (HEVC)** and I cannot understand how many contexts are used for *last_sig_coeff_x,y_prefix* for a 8x8 luma TB.

In the first image a table is reported and I can see that three contexts are adopted: one for the first two bins, one for the third and the fourth bin and one for the fifth bin.

[image]

In the second image another table is reported (taken by the same book describing the standard): here, it seems that the number of contexts for a 8x8 luma TB is equal to 15x2.

[image]

What is the exact number of contexts for this flag?

Answer (score 0):

For who can be interested, I have understood that the second table shows the sum of the number of contexts for all the TB sizes (4x4, 8x8, 16x16 and 32x32). Then, based on the first table we obtain:

> 3 + **3** + 4 + 5 = 15